# What is the difference between linear and relative layout?

Tags: android, layout

What is the difference between linear and relative layout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linear layouts put every child, one after the other, in a line, either horizontally or vertically.  With a relative layout you can give each child a LayoutParam that specifies exactly where is should go, relative to the parent or relative to other children.

Answer (score 15):

***`LINEAR LAYOUT ::`***

- In a linear layout, like the name suggests, all the elements are
  displayed in a linear fashion
- Either Horizontally or Vertically and this behavior is set in
  android:orientation which is an attribute of    the node
  LinearLayout.
- Linear layouts put every child, one after the other, in a line,
  either horizontally or vertically.

[*Click here ---- for --- Android Docs reference for linear layout*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

[image: Pictorial representation]

---

***`RELATIVE LAYOUT::`***

- In a relative layout every element arranges itself relative to other
  elements or a parent element.
- It is helpful while adding views one next to other etc
- With a relative layout you can give each child a LayoutParam that
  specifies exactly where is should go, relative to the parent or
  relative to other children.
- Views are layered on top of each other in relative layout

[*Click here ---- for ---Android Docs reference for Relative layout*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

[image: Pictorial representation]

---

**Optimization**::*Have a look at [**Optimizing Layout Hierarchies**](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)*

**The Fewer Views, the Better**::

1. `The number one goal for your layouts should be using the fewest number of Views possible. The fewer Views you have to work with, the faster your application will run. Excessive nesting of Views further slows down your application.`
2. `A RelativeLayout hierarchy will typically use fewer Views and have a flatter tree than a LinearLayout hierarchy. With LinearLayout, you must create a new LinearLayout every time you want to change the orientation of your views – creating additional Views and a more nested hierarchy. As a result, it is recommended that you first use RelativeLayout for any layout that has any complexity. There is a high probability you will reduce the number of Views – and the depth of your View tree – by doing so.`

Answer (score 4):

From [Android developer documentation: Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

**LinearLayout**

> LinearLayout aligns all children in a single direction — vertically or horizontally, depending on how you define the orientation attribute.

**RelativeLayout**

> RelativeLayout lets child views specify their position relative to the parent view or to each other (specified by ID)

Answer (score 2):

difference is simple: in LinearLayout we arrange stuff in linear manner (one after another), and in RelativeLayout we can place stuff anywhere on screen.

=> Linear Layout is arranged as a list.
Rest they are similar in functionality.

Comment: elaborate your answer

Answer (score 0):

One of the [characteristic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) feature of `LinearLayout` in Android is use of a property called **Weight**, which app can specify using `android:layout_weight`. 
This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen.

On the other hand, `RelativeLayout` do not support weight or in other words, `RelativeLayout` does not pay attention to `android:layout_weight`. That's a property of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, but not of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Layouts**

1. Linear Layouts are great for aligning views in rows and columns.
2. They are a good way to divide up one place using layout weights that will expand or shrink views depending on the size of the Display.

**Relative Layouts**

1. Relative Layouts are great for positioning elements relative to one another.
2. For example putting B below A or putting C in the lower left hand corner.[Check the Screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkiA.png)
3. Relative layout also make it easy to overlap views. For Example : view A is overlapping view B. [Check the Screen-Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gwv9.png)

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` is more flexible than `LinearLayout` but if you have proper knowledge about `LinearLayout` you Can use that too.
For `LinearLayout` every attribute has a significant position hardcoded by the developer.
For `RelativeLayout` you can change the position by relating with others attribute.

Comment: Hi Murad. This is a comment not really an answer. Also, this question already has many responses. Please try avoid providing additional answers to questions unless there is a unique solution to present to the community. [Some tips for answering here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Lastly, RelativeLayout is classified as a 'legacy' layout by Android Studio so developers should avoid it in favour of ConstraintLayout unless they are maintaining an out-dated legacy project. Kind Regards.

Answer (score -1):

The following link should explain visually how the layouts work "Visually"
http://www.droiddraw.org/

Add some components to the window and mess with layouts to see what happens this is how I learned what each one does.

Answer (score -1):

In the relative layout ,all the content in the layout page is related to other contents in the example_layout.xml page

In the case of Linear Layout the elements are displayed in the linear format

Answer (score -1):

The difference between linear and relative layout in android is that in linear layout, the "children" can be placed either horizontally or vertically, but, in relative layout, the children can be placed with relative distance from each other. This is the difference between linear and relative layouts.